# Image not uploading to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Im having some trouble uploading an image with php to phpmyadmin. 
Here is my markup so far.

```
        <form method="post">

            <p>Event Date<span> - eg "23" for the 23rd</span><br /> <input type="text" name="eventDate"  maxlength="2" required /> </p>
            <p>Event Month<span> - eg "Mar" for March</span> <br /><input type="text" name="eventMonth"  maxlength="3" required /> </p>
            <p>Artist Image <br /><input type="file" name="artistImage" required /> </p>
            <p>Artist Name <br /><input type="text" name="artistName"  maxlength="30" required /> </p>
            <p>Location <br /><input type="text" name="location"  maxlength="30" required /> </p>
            <p>Price <br /><input type="text" name="price"  maxlength="10" required /> </p>
            <p>Time <br /><input type="text" name="time"  maxlength="10" required /> </p>

            <input id="eventSubmit" type="submit" name="submitEvent" />

        </form>
```

and here is my php code

`

```
if(isset($_POST['submitEvent'])){

    $addEventDate = $_POST['eventDate'];
    $addEventMonth = $_POST['eventMonth'];
    $addEventName = $_POST['artistName'];
    $addEventLocation = $_POST['location'];
    $addEventPrice = $_POST['price'];
    $addEventTime = $_POST['time'];

    $addEventImg = $_FILES['artistImage']['name'];

    $temp_name1 = $_FILES['artistImage']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1, "img/$addEventImg");

    $ticket= 1;

    $insert_product = "INSERT INTO events (eventDate,eventMonth,artistImg,artistName,location,price,time,buyTicket) VALUES ('$addEventDate','$addEventMonth','$addEventImg','$addEventName','$addEventLocation','$addEventPrice','$addEventTime','$ticket')";

    $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    if($run_product){
        echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted.');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('admin.php','_self');</script>";
    }
}
```

?>`

I have set the database up to take the image as a blob here is a picture of my database [image]

and this is the code that is rendering the products onto the events page.

```
<?php

            $get_events = "select * from events";

            $run_events = mysqli_query($con,$get_events);

            while($row_events = mysqli_fetch_array($run_events)){

                $eventDate = $row_events['eventDate'];
                $eventMonth = $row_events['eventMonth'];
                $artistImg = $row_events['artistImg'];
                $artistName = $row_events['artistName'];
                $location = $row_events['location'];
                $price = $row_events['price'];
                $time = $row_events['time'];
                $buyTicket = $row_events['buyTicket'];


                echo "

                    <div class='eventBox'>

                        <div class='dateBanner'>

                            <p><span>$eventDate</span><br />$eventMonth</p>

                        </div>

                        <img src='img/$artistImg'  alt='event image' />

                        <div class='eventDetails'>
                            <h2>$artistName</h2>

                            <p><span>Location</span> <br /> $location<br /><br /><span>Ticket Price</span> <br /> £$price<br /><br /><span>Time</span> <br />$time<br /><br /></p>

                        </div>

                        <div class='PurchaseTicket'>

                            <h3>Buy Ticket</h3>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                ";

            }
            ?>
```

This works for everything apart from the image. The image just displays the alt tag not the actual image. It also doesn't save the image in the folder either.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it!!

Thanks

Comment: just a note - phpmyadmin is irrelevant here - it uploads to a mysql database regardless of preferred software to use - if this was the case my question in your shoes would be image not uploading to command line which makes no sense - also, look into `$_FILES` - you're not actually doing anything with the image :)

Comment: Don't store image as blob. Instead, upload the file or move it to a directory and store the path to the image as VARCHAR

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/mbM2j

Comment: this is my php code for uploading it

Comment: ill change it to varchar now, thanks :)

Comment: please don't post pictures of your code.  Edit the question to include the relevant information.

Comment: i've put the code on the question, thanks ADyson

Comment: @Allan have you try using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form here it is how `<form actoion="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is for sending media files .

Comment: I was missing that @Pavan

Comment: I had made an error with the   move_uploaded_file() the "img/" should have been concatonated to variable after it, its working now!!